# How Can I Remove This Extra Grid Space?

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can I stop this Grid from expanding vertically and adding all this extra space between the rows?

[image]

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Source="testsquare" />
            <Image Source="testsquare" Grid.Column="1"/>

            <Image Source="testsquare" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Image Source="testsquare" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

---

This is what it should look like (ignore the background color change)
[image]

Comment: You've identified what you don't want to happen.  How you need to specify what you do want to happen.

Comment: I feel that's fairly obvious....

Comment: @bwoogie There is a **spacing** property in `Grid` , you can have a look at my answer to check whether it can solve this problem . If not , you can submit as a bug in GitHub.

Comment: @bwoogie Hi ,if answer be helpful ,thanks for marking or voting it up in andvance . ^.*

Answer (score 0):

Use "Auto" instead of "*"

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```

Comment: That works fine with something like labels... But with images everything gets messed up

Comment: if it is just those 4 images you could try out with 2 stackpanels inside a parent stackpanel instead

Comment: it will be more than just the 4.. and i've also tried using stackpanels as well. the results turned out even worse.

Comment: hm, i tried out switching all * to Auto with WPF and it worked out fine. no more spaces between the images. But it will be the original image size. the image wont be streched. Maybe the StackLayout is causing this? I cannot use it in WPF

Comment: if i set the widths to an absolute, like 200 and the heights to * i get the desired effect. But I need it to scale.

Comment: so the images should scale?

Comment: did you really try out my solution? use only Auto on the rows, not the columns. And add a margin to each image like Margin="5"

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug, where the grid height is being treated as if the image is being displayed at its full height.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="testsquare" />
    <Image Source="testsquare" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spacing) property in `Grid` .

`Grid` has properties to control spacing between rows and columns. The following properties are available for customizing the `Grid`:

- **ColumnSpacing** – the amount of space between columns. The default value of this property is `6`.
- **RowSpacing** – the amount of space between rows. The default value of this property is `6`.

You can set `RowSpacing` or `ColumnSpacing` to check whether can solve it .

```
<StackLayout Padding="5">

    <Grid RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="5">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="icon.png" BackgroundColor="Accent"/>
        <Image Source="icon.png"
               BackgroundColor="Accent"
               Grid.Column="1" />

        <Image Source="icon.png"
               BackgroundColor="Accent"
               Grid.Row="1" />
        <Image Source="icon.png"
               BackgroundColor="Accent"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

About **Image** , The `Aspect` property determines how the image will be scaled to fit the display area, with `Fill` or `AspectFill` .(Default is `AspectFit`)